# expression was too complex to be solved issue in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

I am using below code for showing icloud picker. my code works fine in Xcode 8 but when I updated to Xcode 9 my it shows me error. How to get rid of this issue?

```
let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeText), String(kUTTypePDF), String(kUTTypePNG), String(kUTTypeJPEG), String(kUTTypePlainText), String(kUTTypeImage),"public.data"], in: .import)
```

When use only one item in array as `public.data` then it works.

Comment: break the expression into distinct sub-expressions, use `documentTypes ` value as a separate array.

Comment: thanks for answering but even i used a seprate array it did not work for me

Comment: make it like `let documents : [String] = [String("kUTTypeText"), String("kUTTypePDF"), String("kUTTypePNG"), String("kUTTypeJPEG"), String("kUTTypePlainText"), String("kUTTypeImage"),"public.data"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it.

Try this.

```
let t1 = String(kUTTypeText)
let t2 = String(kUTTypePDF)
let t3 = String(kUTTypePNG)
let t4 = String(kUTTypeJPEG)
let t5 = String(kUTTypePlainText)
let t6 = String(kUTTypeImage)
let t7 = "public.data"

let types = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7]
let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: types, in: .import)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it into multiple lines:

```
let documentTypes: [String] = [String(kUTTypeText), String(kUTTypePDF), String(kUTTypePNG), String(kUTTypeJPEG), String(kUTTypePlainText), String(kUTTypeImage),"public.data"]

let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: documentTypes, in: .import)
```